# How to convert a vector of bonds ZC Spreads into default spreads

Tags: bond, spread, default-probability

If we consider a set of bonds issued by a given entity that are quoted on the market, one can get for each of those bonds a ZC spread on top of reference swap curve (say the bonds are in USD and so we use the leading tenor USD LIBOR 3M).

So assume we end up with:

| Maturity | ZC Spread|

| 1 Year   |  100 bp  |
| 2 Year   |  200 bp  |
| 5 Year   |  350 bp  |
| 10 Year  |  500 bp  |

I understand those are spreads that can be used as parallel shifts per maturity e.g. if we have a bond with a 2 year maturity, that needs to be priced of the above data, we can as an approximation interpolate a spread of 150 bp for 2 years, add it to the USD LIBOR 3M and get a theoretical price for our bond

Question: Is there a quick approximation to convert those ZC spreads into default spreads that can be used per flow payment dates? (i.e. without having to boostrap a basis curve using those bonds on top of USD LIBOR 3M)

Thanks,